# JQuery add tag <a> around <img>

Tags: jquery

How can I add  tag aroud  with link to that image with JQuery?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will wrap a set of images with links to them:

```
$('some selector for the images').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<a href='" + this.src + "'/>");
});
```

...uses `.each` ([link](http://api.jquery.com/each/)), `.wrap` ([link](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)), and the native DOM `src` ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-87762984)) property for image elements.

**Edit** Or as Pointy points out (but not pointedly), just pass a function into `wrap`:

```
$('some selector for the images').wrap(function() {
  return "<a href='" + this.src + "'/>";
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/arozo)

Comment: It's also possible to just use `.wrap()` with a function as an argument; probably a wash.

Comment: @Pointy: *Sigh* When will I learn?! I *know* that, and yet I keep typing `each`... Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't get this working until I realized that I needed to update to the latest jQuery.  Thank you very much @T.J.Crowder and Pointy

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#img').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this); 
    $this.wrap('<a href="' + $this.attr('src') + '"></a>');
});
```

Comment: `#img` should be `img`. It doesn't make sense to select an element that will be unique and use the `each` function. :P

Comment: actually it does, since you need to select the element. i could have done $('#img').wrap('<a href="' + $('#img').attr('src') + '"></a>); but this shows a bit more uses of jquery. valid point though ^_^

Comment: no, Bruno is right. you're calling each on one element. it should be $('img').